# Winapi hook via mhook causes program crash or hang

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am trying to hook [StartDocW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd145114(v=vs.85).aspx) to intercept printing via [mhook](https://github.com/martona/mhook). I use AppInit_DLLs to load my library.

DLL code is simple:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "mhook/mhook-lib/mhook.h"
using StartDocPtr = int(*)(HDC, const DOCINFO*);
StartDocPtr orig;

int HookedStartDocW(HDC hdc, const DOCINFO* lpdi) {
    return orig(hdc, lpdi);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(__in HINSTANCE, __in DWORD Reason, __in LPVOID) {
    orig = (StartDocPtr)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("gdi32"), "StartDocW");
    switch (Reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&orig, &HookedStartDocW);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        Mhook_Unhook((PVOID*)&orig);
        break;
    }
}
```

Hook is working and printing is done OK. But If I change HookStartDocW to following:

```
int HookedStartDocW(HDC hdc, const DOCINFO* lpdi) {
    char buf[40];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buf, 40);
    return orig(hdc, lpdi);
}
```

Programs on printing will crash immediately. Even if I just leave `char buf[40]` and comment `GetModuleHandle` - program will hang. Why is this happening?

Moreover, if program crashes\hangs on printing (if I add anything besides `return orig(hdc, lpdi)`) - PC starts to behave very weirdly, refusing to run programs, etc. If I reboot it - Windows just endlessly spins on boot screen, the only way to bring it back to live - is to boot via liveCD and rename\delete my hook DLL.

Printing programs: Excel 2016, notepad.

Compiler - MSVC 2015, x64 release DLL compilation, using MBCS instead of unicode.

Comment: You've left out the `WINAPI` calling convention from the `StartDocW` signature (both in its replacement and the typedef pointing to the old function), so the stack is being munged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hook is declared wrong.

Look at the actual declaration of `StartDocW()` in `Wingdi.h`:

```
__gdi_entry WINGDIAPI int WINAPI StartDocW(__in HDC hdc, __in CONST DOCINFOW *lpdi);
```

You can ignore `__gdi_entry`. `WINGDIAPI` simply resolves to `__declspec(dllimport)`.  What is important in this declaration is the `WINAPI`.

Like *almost all* Win32 API functions, `StartDocW()` uses the `__stdcall` calling convention.  The `WINAPI` macro resolves to `__stdcall`.

Your code does not specify any calling convention at all, so it uses your compiler's default, which is usually `__cdecl` instead.  So you are mismanaging the call stack.  That is why your code crashes.

You are also using `DOCINFO` when you should be using `DOCINFOW` instead.  It is clear in your code that you are compiling for MBCS and not for UNICODE, so `DOCINFO` maps to `DOCINFOA`.  You can't pass a `DOCINFOA` to `StartDocW()`, it expects a `DOCINFOW` instead.

You need to fix your declarations, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "mhook/mhook-lib/mhook.h"

using StartDocPtr = int (WINAPI *)(HDC, const DOCINFOW*);
StartDocPtr orig = nullptr;

int WINAPI HookedStartDocW(HDC hdc, const DOCINFOW* lpdi) {
    //...
    return orig(hdc, lpdi);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(__in HINSTANCE, __in DWORD Reason, __in LPVOID) {
    orig = (StartDocPtr) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("gdi32")), "StartDocW");
    switch (Reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&orig, &HookedStartDocW);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        Mhook_Unhook((PVOID*)&orig);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I initially assumed a calling convention mismatch, too. But the OP is compiling x64 code. What am I missing?

Comment: @IInspectable there is still the `DOCINFO` mismatch